# How much does post-GoF Voldemort remember about events in PS?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

Is there any canon evidence of exactly how much does post-GoF Voldemort remember about events in PS (e.g. what happened when he occupied the insides of Quirrell's turban)?

Comment: Is there a reason he might not have retained such memories?

Comment: He briefly mentions attempting to steal the stone in the graveyard scene, but there's no indication that he has less but normal memories of that time.

Comment: @Voldemort - you tell me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes, he remembers what happened while he possessed Quirrell.

When the Dark Lord explains to his Death Eaters how he survived every circumstance he faced, he gives a synopsis of what happened while he possessed Quirrell. He doesn't go into the small details, because possessing Quirrell and trying to steal the Stone was only a small part of his story, which spanned years in total.  He described the chain of events well enough, though, that it shows he remembers it. He mentions how he saw Quirrell as his opportunity to get the Stone and gain immortality, how that plan was unsuccessful because of Harry Potter, and how Quirrell died and he moved on but still in his weakened form.

> “Then … four years ago … the means for my return seemed assured. A wizard – young, foolish and gullible – wandered across my path in the forest I had made my home. Oh, he seemed the very chance I had been dreaming of … for he was a teacher at Dumbledore’s school … he was easy to bend to my will … he brought me back to this country, and after a while, I took possession of his body, to supervise him closely as he carried out my orders. But my plan failed. I did not manage to steal the Philosopher’s Stone. I was not to be assured immortal life. I was thwarted … thwarted, once again, by Harry Potter …’
>
> Silence once more; nothing was stirring, not even the leaves on the yew tree. The Death Eaters were quite motionless, the glittering eyes in their masks fixed upon Voldemort, and upon Harry.
> ‘The servant died when I left his body, and I was left as weak as ever I had been,’ Voldemort continued.” 
>  <sub><sup>- *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 33 (The Death Eaters)*</sup></sub>

Comment: Voldemort clearly remembers Quirrel being unable to touch Harry; that is why he uses Harry's blood to help reconstitute his body, to get over that barrier. But it ended up backfiring...

Answer (score 2):

I think its safe to assume that Post GoF Voldemort will retain all memories of his time possessing Quirrell.

1. We have 0 evidence that he forgot anything.
2. We know that it was the primary piece of his soul possessing Quirrell, the piece that contains all of his memories.
3. We Know that he retained the memories of other possessions that were similar to this, such as the animals he possessed while hiding.
4. We know that after he regains his body, he is able to posses other creatures, such as Nagini, in a very dominate fashion most likely due to the fact that he has a fragment of his soul attached to her, and appears to have full control/memory of the possessions.
5. He actually mentions that he was thwarted in the retrieval of the philosophers stone. So he acknowledges that he indeed has some of the memories of this event, as at this time, no one else who hes been in contact with would have known this event occurred. We can assume that other then Harry and the gang, only Snape and Dumbledore would have known the extent of his attempt on the stone, and in the graveyard he had not yet come back into contact with Snape.

Comment: And 6. When he describes his whole story to the Death Eaters at the end of _GoF_, he describes, with quite some level of details, events that happened to him (the same piece of his soul as the one from _PS_) both right before and after the events in _PS_. And Snape also says (or implies?) later on (“Spinner’s End” in _HBP_, if memory serves) that he was called on by Voldemort to explain why he hadn’t helped Quirrell/Voldemort get the Stone.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Number 3 was referencing to this, though it was poorly worded, he was talking about how he was living and possessing animal after animal while in his disembodied soul form prior to meeting quirrell.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that—I just thought it worth adding that these memories are actually specified as happening both before _and_ after the events in _PS_, so it would make very little sense for him not to remember the events in _PS_ themselves, unless he hit his head and got random amnesia at some point …